# Manter selecionado um combobox com angular

Tags: angularjs

Estou utilizando o angularJs para preencher os dados de um formulário dentro de uma modal.
tenho uma função `editarSolicitacao(solicitacao)` que é executada a partir do evento click do botão. Quando a modal abre o campo vem selecionado porém a seleção some rapidamente e notei que é criado a seguinte tag no HTML

```
<option value="? number:7 ?"></option>


 <select ng-model="solicitacao.setor_id" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">(Selecione)</option>
                        <option ng-value="setor.id" ng-repeat="setor in setores" ng-bind="setor.id" ng-selected="setor.id == solicitacao.setor_id"></option>
                        </select>
```

Alguém já passou por algo parecido e sabe me dizer como devo proceder?

minha função que abre a modal e preeche o formulário:

```
$scope.editarSolicitacao = function(solicitacao)
    {
        unidadeMedidas();
        setores();

        $scope.solicitacao = solicitacao;
        $scope.produtos = $scope.solicitacao.produtos_adicionados;
        $scope.showProdutos = true;

        modal();
    }



 unidadeMedidas = function()
    {
         $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/unidade-medida/consultar'
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.unidades = response.data;

        },function(responseError){
            wgmAlert(responseError.statusText);
        });
    }



    setores = function()
    {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/setores'
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.setores = response.data;

        },function(responseError){
            wgmAlert(responseError.statusText);
        });
    }



    modal = function()
    {
        $scope.modal = Modal({
            animation: 'slideDown',
            draggable: true,
            width: $(window).outerWidth() -300,
            title: 'Solicitação',
            height: $(window).outerHeight() - 100,
            template: $('#template-form-solicitacao').html(),
            clickOut: false
        },$scope);
        $scope.modal.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você criou seu ?

Você está setando o ng-model? Como está sendo gerada das options?

Um exemplo:

```
<select ng-model="suamodel" name="selectUm">
<options ng-repeat="optionsValue as modelComOptions" value={{optionsValue.id}}>{{ optionsValue.descricao }}</options>
</select>
```

[Documentação Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Quando abro a modal pela primeira vez ele fica selecionado. Se eu fechar e abrir novamente ele não mantem selecionado.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema.

Comment: @MiguelBatista estou com esse mesmo problema pode me informar como resolveu?